# TypeError: undefined is not an object, react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-emulator, runtime-error

I added a new state to my application to know whether the user is logged in or not, and this error shows up during the runtime now!

[image: the error]

Before adding this, everything was great, everything was working fine, I tried looking for this error but everybody mentioned some babel-react which I don't use. As I mentioned clearing cache didn't help. I haven't upgraded react native lately, so it's not because of the update. ESLint doesn't show error at all.
Main problem is with this 'isloggedin' boolean state wariable, but I don't realize what the issue may be.
Any kind of advice or help would be amazing.
Thank's in advance.

I've tried cleaning the cache, restarting everything

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header, Button } from './components/common';
import Loginform from './components/Loginform';

class App extends Component {
    state = { isloggedin: false };
    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: 'AIzaSyDN_m1VetpIBLji_S8Hng1zbPlNwaQTBiI',
            authDomain: 'authentication-83b93.firebaseapp.com',
            databaseURL: 'https://authentication-83b93.firebaseio.com',
            projectId: 'authentication-83b93',
            storageBucket: '',
            messagingSenderId: '863329573565',
            appId: '1:863329573565:web:08bedbdc76995c53'
          }
        );
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({ isloggedin: true });
            } else {
                this.setState({ isloggedin: false });
            }
        });
    }
    renderContent() {
        if (this.user.isloggedin) {
            return (
                <Button>
                    Log Out
                </Button>
            )
        } else
        return <Loginform />;
    }
     render() {
        return (
        <View>
            <Header headerText="HopeSter Log In" />
            {this.renderContent()}
        </View>
        );
    }
}
export  default App;
```

Comment: `this.user` is never set anywhere? You only seem to use `this.state.isloggedin`

Comment: Replace `this.user.isloggedin` with `this.state.isloggedin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the state as condition in 2 ways

First,

```
renderContent() {
        if (this.state.isloggedin) {
            return (
                <Button>
                    Log Out
                </Button>
            )
        } else
        return <Loginform />;
    }
```

second,

```
renderContent() {
       const{isloggedin}=this.state
        if (isloggedin) {
            return (
                <Button>
                    Log Out
                </Button>
            )
        } else
        return <Loginform />;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to take field `isloggedin` from the object `this.user`. However, there is no such object, you saved that property in the state. So it can be fixed next way:

```js
    renderContent() {
        if (this.state.isloggedin) {
            return (
                <Button>
                    Log Out
                </Button>
            )
        } else
        return <Loginform />;
    }
```